# mySQL backup and restore c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

The code have no errors. but when the I back up,the size of the file is 0kb or 1kb only. And when I restore nothing happens. All data is still deleted.

**Back up Code:**

```
string path;
path = "D:\\MySqlBackup"+ ".sql";
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);


ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName ="C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe";
psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.Arguments = "--user=root --password=database --database=hotelreservationandbillingsystem < D:\\MySqlBackup.sql";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = Process.Start(psi);
string output;
output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
file.WriteLine(output);
process.WaitForExit();
file.Close();
process.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Back Up Successfully!","Saved",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

**Restore Code:**

```
string path;
path = "D:\\MySqlBackup.sql";
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
string input = file.ReadToEnd();
file.Close();

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe";
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.Arguments = "--user=root --password=database --database=hotelreservationandbillingsystem < D:\\MySqlBackup.sql";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;


Process process = Process.Start(psi);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
process.StandardInput.Close();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Restored Successfully!", "Restored", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not you should try a more easiest way of taking backup and restore option available 
[MySqlBackup.NET - MySQL Backup Solution for C#](https://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/)

Where the code for **Backup** is

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mb.ExportToFile(file);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And **Restore**

```
string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mb.ImportFromFile(file);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to add reference? for the MySqlBackup?

Comment: Yes, You need Prerequisite
MySqlBackup.NET relies on the following component to work.
MySQL dot net Connector/Net (MySql.Data.DLL)
A reference of this DLL must be added into your project in order for MySqlBackup.NET to work.
MySql.Data.DLL is developed by Oracle Corporation, licensed under GPL License (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html).